# The function 'draw_label' should be called on each calculation for consistency

Tags: pine-script

I'm struggling to fix the following warnings. How can I fix them?

> line 158: The function 'draw_label' should be called on each calculation for consistency. It is recommended to extract the call from this scope.
> line 161: The function 'draw_label' should be called on each calculation for consistency. It is recommended to extract the call from this scope.
> line 164: The function 'draw_label' should be called on each calculation for consistency. It is recommended to extract the call from this scope.
> line 167: The function 'draw_label' should be called on each calculation for consistency. It is recommended to extract the call from this scope.
> line 170: The function 'draw_label' should be called on each calculation for consistency. It is recommended to extract the call from this scope.
> line 173: The function 'draw_label' should be called on each calculation for consistency. It is recommended to extract the call from this scope.
> line 176: The function 'draw_label' should be called on each calculation for consistency. It is recommended to extract the call from this scope.
> line 179: The function 'draw_label' should be called on each calculation for consistency. It is recommended to extract the call from this scope.
> line 182: The function 'draw_label' should be called on each calculation for consistency. It is recommended to extract the call from this scope.
> line 185: The function 'draw_label' should be called on each calculation for consistency. It is recommended to extract the call from this scope.

```
//@version=4
study("Support Resistance", overlay = true)
prd = input(defval = 10, title="Pivot Period", minval = 4, maxval = 30)
ppsrc = input(defval = 'Close/Open', title="Source", options = ['High/Low', 'Close/Open'])
maxnumpp = input(defval = 20, title =" Maximum Number of Pivot", minval = 5, maxval = 100)
ChannelW = input(10, title = "Maximum Channel Width %", minval = 1)
maxnumsr = input(5, title =" Maximum Number of S/R", minval = 1, maxval = 10)
min_strength = input(2, title =" Minimum Strength", minval = 1, maxval = 10)
linestyle = input(defval = 'Dashed', title = "Line Style", options = ['Solid', 'Dotted', 'Dashed'])
linewidth = input(defval = 2, title = "Line Width", minval = 1, maxval = 4)
resistancecolor = input(defval = color.red, title = "Resistance Color", type = input.color)
supportcolor = input(defval = color.lime, title = "Support Color", type = input.color)
showpp = input(false, title = "Show Point Points")

float ph = na, float pl = na
float src1 =  ppsrc == 'High/Low' ? high : max(close, open)
float src2 =  ppsrc == 'High/Low' ? low: min(close, open)
ph := pivothigh(src1, prd, prd)
pl := pivotlow(src2, prd, prd)

plotshape(ph and showpp, text = "H",  style = shape.labeldown, color = na, textcolor = color.red, location = location.abovebar, transp = 0, offset = -prd)
plotshape(pl and showpp, text = "L",  style = shape.labelup, color = na, textcolor = color.lime, location = location.belowbar, transp = 0, offset = -prd)

//calculate maximum S/R channel zone width
prdhighest =  highest(300)
prdlowest = lowest(300)
cwidth = (prdhighest - prdlowest) * ChannelW / 100

var pivotvals= array.new_float(0)

if ph or pl
    array.unshift(pivotvals, ph ? ph : pl)
    if array.size(pivotvals) > maxnumpp // limit the array size
        array.pop(pivotvals)

get_sr_vals(ind)=>
    float lo = array.get(pivotvals, ind)
    float hi = lo
    int numpp = 0
    for y = 0 to array.size(pivotvals) - 1
        float cpp = array.get(pivotvals, y)
        float wdth = cpp <= lo ? hi - cpp : cpp - lo
        if wdth <= cwidth // fits the max channel width?
            lo := cpp <= lo ? cpp : lo
            hi := cpp > lo ? cpp : hi
            numpp := numpp + 1
    [hi, lo, numpp]  

var sr_up_level = array.new_float(0)
var sr_dn_level = array.new_float(0)
sr_strength = array.new_float(0)

find_loc(strength)=>
    ret = array.size(sr_strength)
    if ret > 0
        for i = array.size(sr_strength) - 1 to 0
            if strength <= array.get(sr_strength, i)
                break
            ret := i
    ret

check_sr(hi, lo, strength)=>
    ret = true
    if array.size(sr_up_level) > 0
        for i = 0 to array.size(sr_up_level) - 1
            //included?
            if array.get(sr_up_level, i) >= lo and array.get(sr_up_level, i) <= hi  or 
               array.get(sr_dn_level, i) >= lo and array.get(sr_dn_level, i) <= hi
                if strength >= array.get(sr_strength, i)
                    array.remove(sr_strength, i)
                    array.remove(sr_up_level, i)
                    array.remove(sr_dn_level, i)
                    ret
                else
                    ret := false
                break
    ret

//get min time
var int btime = time
btime := na(time[1]) ? btime : min(btime, time - time[1])

round_it(value)=> 
    round(value / syminfo.mintick) * syminfo.mintick

draw_line(ycoor, Lstyle)=>
    line.new(x1 = bar_index, 
             y1 = ycoor, 
             x2 = bar_index - 1, 
             y2 = ycoor, 
             extend = extend.both,
             color = ycoor >= close ? resistancecolor : supportcolor, 
             style = Lstyle, 
             width = linewidth) 

st = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', time)
cl = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', time_close)
opened = timenow > st and timenow < cl
    
draw_label(ycoor)=>
    rate = 100 * (ycoor - close) / close
    label.new(x = opened ? time + btime * 30 : time[100], 
              y = ycoor, text = tostring(ycoor) + "(" + tostring(rate,'#.##') + "%)", 
              color = ycoor >= close ? color.red : color.lime,
              textcolor = ycoor >= close ? color.white : color.black, 
              style = ycoor >= close ? label.style_labeldown : label.style_labelup, 
              xloc = xloc.bar_time, 
              yloc = yloc.price)

set_lx(lab, lin)=>
    rate = 100 * (label.get_y(lab) - close) / close
    label.set_text(lab, text = tostring(label.get_y(lab)) + "(" + tostring(rate,'#.##') + "%)")
    label.set_x(lab, x = opened ? time + btime * 30 : time[100])
    label.set_color(lab, color = label.get_y(lab) >= close ? color.red : color.lime)
    label.set_textcolor(lab, textcolor = label.get_y(lab) >= close ? color.white : color.black)
    label.set_style(lab, style = label.get_y(lab) >= close ? label.style_labeldown : label.style_labelup)
    line.set_color(lin, color = line.get_y1(lin) >= close ? resistancecolor : supportcolor) 

var line l1 = na, var line l2 = na, var line l3 = na, var line l4 = na, var line l5 = na, var line l6 = na, var line l7 = na, var line l8 = na, var line l9 = na, var line l10 = na
var label lb1 = na, var label lb2 = na, var label lb3 = na, var label lb4 = na, var label lb5 = na, var label lb6 = na, var label lb7 = na, var label lb8 = na, var label lb9 = na, var label lb10 = na

set_lx(lb1, l1), set_lx(lb2, l2), set_lx(lb3, l3), set_lx(lb4, l4), set_lx(lb5, l5), set_lx(lb6, l6), set_lx(lb7, l7), set_lx(lb8, l8), set_lx(lb9, l9), set_lx(lb10, l10)

if ph or pl
    //because of new calculation, remove old S/R levels
    array.clear(sr_up_level)
    array.clear(sr_dn_level)
    array.clear(sr_strength)
    //find S/R zones
    for x = 0 to array.size(pivotvals) - 1
        [hi, lo, strength] = get_sr_vals(x)
        if check_sr(hi, lo, strength)
            loc = find_loc(strength)
            // if strength is in first maxnumsr sr then insert it to the arrays 
            if loc < maxnumsr and strength >= min_strength
                array.insert(sr_strength, loc, strength)
                array.insert(sr_up_level, loc, hi)
                array.insert(sr_dn_level, loc, lo)
                // keep size of the arrays = 5
                if array.size(sr_strength) > maxnumsr
                    array.pop(sr_strength)
                    array.pop(sr_up_level)
                    array.pop(sr_dn_level)
    
    line.delete(l1), line.delete(l2), line.delete(l3), line.delete(l4), line.delete(l5), line.delete(l6), line.delete(l7), line.delete(l8), line.delete(l9), line.delete(l10)
    label.delete(lb1), label.delete(lb2), label.delete(lb3), label.delete(lb4), label.delete(lb5), label.delete(lb6), label.delete(lb7), label.delete(lb8), label.delete(lb9), label.delete(lb10)
    if array.size(sr_up_level)
        Lstyle = linestyle == 'Dashed' ? line.style_dashed :
                 linestyle == 'Solid' ? line.style_solid :
                 line.style_dotted
        for x = 0 to array.size(sr_up_level) - 1
            float mid = round_it((array.get(sr_up_level, x) + array.get(sr_dn_level, x)) / 2)
            if x == 0
                l1 := draw_line(mid, Lstyle)
                lb1 := draw_label(mid)
            if x == 1
                l2 := draw_line(mid, Lstyle)
                lb2 := draw_label(mid)
            if x == 2
                l3 := draw_line(mid, Lstyle)
                lb3 := draw_label(mid)
            if x == 3
                l4 := draw_line(mid, Lstyle)
                lb4 := draw_label(mid)
            if x == 4
                l5 := draw_line(mid, Lstyle)
                lb5 := draw_label(mid)
            if x == 5
                l6 := draw_line(mid, Lstyle)
                lb6 := draw_label(mid)
            if x == 6
                l7 := draw_line(mid, Lstyle)
                lb7 := draw_label(mid)
            if x == 7
                l8 := draw_line(mid, Lstyle)
                lb8 := draw_label(mid)
            if x == 8
                l9 := draw_line(mid, Lstyle)
                lb9 := draw_label(mid)
            if x == 9
                l10 := draw_line(mid, Lstyle)
                lb10 := draw_label(mid)

f_crossed_over()=>
    ret = false
    if array.size(sr_up_level) > 0
        for x = 0 to array.size(sr_up_level) - 1
            float mid = round_it((array.get(sr_up_level, x) + array.get(sr_dn_level, x)) / 2)
            if close[1] <= mid and close > mid
                ret := true
    ret

f_crossed_under()=>
    ret = false
    if array.size(sr_up_level) > 0
        for x = 0 to array.size(sr_up_level) - 1
            float mid = round_it((array.get(sr_up_level, x) + array.get(sr_dn_level, x)) / 2)
            if close[1] >= mid and close < mid
                ret := true
    ret

alertcondition(f_crossed_over(), title='Resistance Broken', message='Resistance Broken')
alertcondition(f_crossed_under(), title='Support Broken', message='Support Broken')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid warnings if you will extract time builtin variables to global scope. This builtin should be used on every bar for consistency, and function which uses this builtin in conditional expressions, by default is marked as a function with unpredictable behavior, with throwing warning.

You need smth like this:

```
***
_t1 = time
_t2 = time[100]
draw_label(ycoor)=>
    rate = 100 * (ycoor - close) / close
    label.new(x = opened ? _t1 + btime * 30 : _t2, 
              y = ycoor, text = tostring(ycoor) + "(" + tostring(rate,'#.##') + "%)", 
              color = ycoor >= close ? color.red : color.lime,
              textcolor = ycoor >= close ? color.white : color.black, 
              style = ycoor >= close ? label.style_labeldown : label.style_labelup, 
              xloc = xloc.bar_time, 
              yloc = yloc.price)
***
```